# Reading text file with variable number of entries in matlab

Tags: matlab, file

I have text file that looks like the following for example

```
1 12 34
67 56 78 98 98
...
```

Basically row of numbers, but the row size isn't fixed.
Is there a quick way to read this in matlab, and maybe store the content in a cell array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`importdata` would read your file and fill up the empty spaces with NaNs, that could be used.

Or you parse your file directly:

```
str = fileread('file.txt'); %read your file into a string
data = cellfun(@(line) cellfun(@str2double, strsplit(line, ' '), 'UniformOutput', false), strsplit(str, '\r\n'), 'UniformOutput', false);
```

strsplit splits at the return statement -> first cell array

Use those cell-arrays as input and split them per space.

```
data = cellfun(@(line) str2double(strsplit(line, ' ')), strsplit(str, '\r\n'), 'UniformOutput', false);
```

You could also use the str2double to convert the cell array to numbers directly, but then it'll be a normal array, which means that the access would be data{1}(2) instead of data{1}{2} and I would prefer to keep the styles aligned.

Comment: The only thing is that it seems it leaves the numbers as characters, can this be fixed?

Answer (score 0):

try [textscan](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/textscan.html)

```
str = fopen('test.txt');
data = textscan(str,'%s','Delimiter','\n');
%data = textscan(str,'%f');
fclose(str);
```